# Field position in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I was wondering, how can I move my date field to the right edge of my `RecyclerView`? It should be placed in the same line as the magnitude but on the opposite side. Any gravity methods doesn't seem to work. Is it possible to do that in `LinearLayout` or should I make this in another type of layout? Here's the screenshot of my app and xml file of the layout.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="128dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/place_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/magnitude"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/magnitude_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/magnitude_type"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/magType_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/significance"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/significance_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/alert"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/alert_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this should do the trick :

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/place_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/magnitude"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/magnitude_text_view"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_text_view"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/magnitude_type"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/magType_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/significance"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/significance_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/alert"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/alert_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks ;) It helps me a lot :)

Comment: @LukaszWachowski Just edited it, should be just fine now

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:minHeight="12<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>8dp"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/place_text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/magnitude"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/magnitude_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/magnitude_type"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/magType_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/significance"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/significance_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/alert"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/alert_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```